# three points (two slopes) op amp conditioning circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, comparator, conditioning, linearity

I'd like to get the output on the right when applying the signal on the left to a signal conditioning circuit using op amps. 
[image]

I've got different slopes so I guess I need two amplifier circuits with different gains (16 and 24 plus a 2V offset). Even so how do I select one of the two? Using a third op amp used as a comparator? Is there a more obvious solution?

Comment: Why not do the obvious and start with the signal on the right which is linear. Define tolerance errors for gain and offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you are asking with one dual op-amp. R1 and R3 give the gain of 16, and R2 increases the gain when the input voltage rises above 250mV. OA2 saturates to the positive supply for lower inputs. Since temperature is the variable, presumably speed is not of concern.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5J8fp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: That's a clever solution. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Since the gain must vary, and you have not defined any error band at the gain-switch point, you can use diodes in the opamp feedback path to change the gain as needed.